# How to use virtual columns in a reactive-table in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using a template for columns and an object for the collection field.I want to add sub-labels for one of the columns.

```
settings: function() {
    return {
        collection: Template.instance().collectionObject.get("data"),
        class: "bordered striped highlight fixed",
        fields: [
            {key: "nameDate", label: "Names", tmpl: Template.nameTeleCallingReport},
            {key: "units", label: "Units", tmpl: Template.unitsTeleCallingReport},
        ],
    }
}
```

In the second field with label "Units",  I want subheaders like: "pending, in-process and trashed". 
In the official documentation I read about virtual coulmns. But I am unable to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize a function in the units key to return a different value than what it is. Let's say you return 0/1/2 as the value but want to return the strings you mentioned:

```
{
    key: 'units',
    label: 'Units',
    tmpl: Template.nameTeleCallingReport,
    fn: function (value, object, key) { 
      if( value === 0 ) { return "pending"; }
      else if ( value === 1 ) { return "in-process"; };
      else { return "trashed"; }
    }
}
```

You'll obviously have to adjust the logic in your function to do what you want, but that should get you started.